# What does the => symbol do in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to learning haskell, so I don't really understand the typing system when it comes to constraints. There's this weird `=>` symbol that doesn't make sense to me. Is it actually just syntax? Or is it a type constructor? I'm not sure. Below are my thoughts about it. Can someone clarify what exactly `=>` means in haskell?

In haskell, `(->)` is a type constructor, with kind `* -> * -> *`. This is nice, because it makes it clear why, for example, `Double -> Bool` has kind `*`. But then I wondered about types like `(Integral a) => a -> a`. Clearly, this has kind `*`, and `a -> a` has kind `*` (I think). Since `Integral` has kind `* -> Constraint`, `Integral a` must have kind `Constraint`. Then, I conclude that `(=>)` has kind Constraint -> * -> *. However, when I type `:k (=>)` in GHCi, I get an error ("parse error on input =>")! This seems to indicate that `(=>)` is not a type constructor. Then what is it?

GHCi also tells me that `(Show List, Read List)` has kind `Constraint`, but that `(,)` has kind `* -> * -> *`, which makes me very confused. Does `(,)` have two definitions? Are constraints some magical hocus-pocus that I just don't understand?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The => is just there as a delimiter between context and type when you write a type signature. They aren't even saved after compilation. You can see it here:
http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html